Why the definition of coprime ideals cannot be $I\cap J=IJ$
As we know, two positive integers $a,b$ are called coprime when $\gcd(a,b)=1$ or equivalently $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)=ab$. By Bézout's Theorem there exist $m,n$ so that $ma+nb=1$, and reversely if $ma+nb=1,a,b\neq0$ then $a,b$ are coprime.
So, if we want to define the coprime relatioship of the ideals $I=(a),J=(b)$ of $\mathbb Z$, we can use rather $ab=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ or $ma+nb=1$. For the first condition we get $IJ=I\cap J$, for the second condition we get $I+J=\mathbb Z$. And the two definetion are equivalence.
But, at a general commutative ring $R$ with unit, the relationship coprime of two ideal $I,J$ is defined by $I+J=R$, not $IJ=I\cap J$. And I was told that $IJ=I\cap J$ cannot be a replacement defination.
So, why $I+J=R$ is good, $IJ=I\cap J$ is bad? And how should the ring $R$ be so that $I+J=R$ is equivalent to $IJ=I\cap J$?

I vote to close since this is rather opinion-based. In this setting, there is no "good" or "bad" choice of definition. It's just a naming thing. You can also call ideals with $IJ = I \cap J$ "weakly coprime" and study these. Nothing of the existing theory (about coprime ideals) will change. Also notice that the Chinese Remainder Theorem for rings does require coprime ideals.

Your second question (btw, try to focus on one question only per post) is a duplicate and has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126121 (I found that by using the site search for 2 minutes.)
